# What to choose yarn-cluster or yarn-client for a reporting platform?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

What I'm planning to do is develop a reporting platform using existing data. I have an existing RDBMS which has large number of records. So I'm using. ([Hadoop 2.7, Spark, Hive, JasperReports, Scoop - Architecuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635234/hadoop-2-7-spark-hive-jasperreports-scoop-architecuture))

- Scoop - Extract data from RDBMS to Hadoop
- Hadoop - Storage platform
- Hive - Datawarehouse
- Spark - Since Hive is more like batch processing Spark on Hive will speed up things
- JasperReports - To generate reports.

Given that I have already read the following

- [What is yarn-client mode in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793694/spark-yarn-client-mode)
- [Difference between yarn-client mode and yarn-cluster mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651335/difference-between-yarn-client-mode-and-yarn-cluster-mode)

Which mode should I use? Why? Decision is based on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some more info to Danier Darabos answer : ***Apart from hosting application/faillover and where Driver runs ( Application Master in yarn-cluster mode or Client in yarn-client mode***, other features remains same. But yarn-client mode supports spark-shell unlike yarn-cluster mode.

[image]

***Have a look at this [article](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/) to know the difference between running Spark application in various modes - YARN Cluster , YARN Client & Spark Stand alone modes***

Take a calculated decision after considering criteria in all options.

Comment: Is that means if I run YARN Cluster, I can't run Hive on Spark?

Comment: From this article, cloudera supports hive in yarn cluster mode: http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html. But Spark Shell can be used for many purposes

Comment: I didn't get you, can I can't I run Hive on Spark in a YARN cluster?

Comment: You can run hive in spark cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The decision is about whether you want your application to run as a YARN application or not.

A non-YARN application (which you get in `yarn-client` mode) is simpler. It's a classical Linux application, you can start it like any application and it runs on that machine like any application.

A YARN application (which you get in `yarn-cluster` mode) is managed by YARN. It runs on whatever machine YARN decides to put it on. If it dies, YARN will restart it, perhaps on a different machine. It is more robust (e.g. it will get restarted if the machine dies) but at the cost of complexity (e.g. you don't have a fixed IP address for the application).

I'd go with `yarn-client` at first. You can switch to `yarn-cluster` later if you find you need the features it provides.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Considering the nature of my application what's the most suitable

Comment: Given your description in the linked question I think you will benefit from `yarn-cluster` mode in the long term.

Comment: One last question, could you please explain why? what's the reason you think like that?

Comment: In the linked question you write _"I want to support fail-over"_. So I guess you don't want the application to go down if a single machine fails. So you need YARN, so it will restart the application on another node in that case.